# Reading in a copy of `/usr/share/dict/words` is 10x slower than the file itself

Tags: linux, files, c, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was experimenting with dictionary implementations in C and found `/usr/share/dict/words` to be a pretty good file for testing. For whatever reason, I wanted to make a copy of the words file into my working directory, but to my surprise the program was noticeably slower in reading the file. What could explain this behaviour? The two files are identical.

If I had to guess, it could be that `/usr/share/dict/words` is already buffered in memory because it's a frequently used file?

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define GET_TIME(now)                           \
    do {                                        \
        struct timeval t;                       \
        gettimeofday(&t, NULL);                 \
        now = t.tv_sec + t.tv_usec / 1000000.0; \
    } while (0)

#define REPORT(msg, time)                   \
    do {                                    \
        printf("%-10s- %f\n", msg, time);   \
    } while (0)

#define SHOW_INVALID    0

struct dict {
    int n;
    char *data[110000];
};

int valid_word(char *input)
{
    for (int i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
        if (!islower(input[i]) && !(input[i] == '\n')) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

struct dict *get_dict(char *file)
{
    struct dict *dict = calloc(1, sizeof(struct dict));
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    char input[128];
    while (fgets(input, 128, fp)) {
        if (valid_word(input)) {
            dict->data[dict->n++] = strdup(input);
        } else {
#if SHOW_INVALID == 1
            printf("Skipping invalid word %s", input);
#endif
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return dict;
}

void destroy_dict(struct dict *dict)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dict->n; i++) {
        free(dict->data[i]);
    }
    free(dict);
}

int search(struct dict *dict, int l, int r, char *word)
{
    if (l > r) return -1;
    int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
    if (!strcmp(dict->data[mid], word)) return mid;
    if (strcmp(dict->data[mid], word) > 0) return search(dict, l, mid - 1, word);
    return search(dict, mid + 1, r, word);
}

int match(struct dict *dict, char *word)
{
    return search(dict, 0, dict->n - 1, word);
}

void test(struct dict *dict, char *file)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    char input[128];
    while (fgets(input, 128, fp)) {
        if (valid_word(input)) {
            assert(match(dict, input) != -1);
        } else {
            assert(match(dict, input) == -1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{
    double init, start, end;
    GET_TIME(init);

    GET_TIME(start);
    struct dict *dict = get_dict("words");
    GET_TIME(end);
    REPORT("setup", end - start);

    GET_TIME(start);
    test(dict, "words");
    GET_TIME(end);
    REPORT("words", end - start);

    GET_TIME(start);
    test(dict, "words_random");
    GET_TIME(end);
    REPORT("randwords", end - start);

    GET_TIME(start);
    destroy_dict(dict);
    GET_TIME(end);
    REPORT("teardown", end - start);

    puts("");
    REPORT("total", end - init);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What program? Where is the "working directory"? How did you measure reading speed?

Comment: Is your working directory on a networked filesystem?

Comment: @Vilinkameni I've added my code.

Comment: @they No. I am using WSL2 though.

Comment: Again, what is the location of the "working directory"? It can make a difference in GNU/Linux if it is on another physical device or another filesystem type than the partition /usr/share/dict is on. I never used WSL, so I'm not sure of its specifics. Also, please update your question, adding that it concerns WSL.

Comment: @Vilinkameni I think you're right. The working directory is outside of WSL, and even though my WSL virtual disk is on the same drive as my working directory, it appears that accessing anything outside the virtual disk incurs a performance hit (due to mounting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vilinkameni noted, I/O performance can differ in GNU/Linux if the files being accessed are on a different physical device or filesystem type.

In my case, WSL2 uses a virtual hard disk but my working directory (that WSL was `cd`'d to) was actually on my `C:/` drive. So, in accessing the `/usr/share/dict/words` file I'm remaining in the WSL2 VHD, but if I copy the file over to my `C:/` drive, that's where the performance hit happens—because it has to read the file on another "filesystem".

I tested this by moving my program to `/usr/share/dict/`, creating a copy of the `words` file there, and the performance is now identical.